# Displaying data connected to the logged in user

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm building a website where users log in and then are redirected to another page. I want to display their usernames and profile pictures in the top bar, but my code doesn't work.
I use the code below, which now that I think of it obviously couldn't work, bacause it will always display the first username and picture in the database. But I don't know how to fix that so that it displays the username and picture of the user who have logged in.

**HTML and PHP**

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_user = "SELECT username, profilepic FROM user";
$user = mysql_query($query_user, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($user);
$totalRows_user = mysql_num_rows($user);
?>

<div id="top">
  <img src="images/<?php echo $row_user['profilepic']; ?>">
  <?php echo $row_user['username']; ?></a>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
**Login script**

```
<?php 
if (isset($_REQUEST['login'])){

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `username` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1){
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
header('Location: content.php');
}else{
echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
}
}
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
header('Location: content.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: no where conditio in query?

Comment: you are selecting all the users from your `user` table... and then when you are using `mysql_fetch_assoc` function its fetching you the first user, that obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store the usename in session after login code like this

```
<?php

session_start();

.......

//your php login code which validates the username and password ...

.......

//then here

    $_SESSION['valid_user']=$username;//$username is who is logged in
```

now in the above use this session value like this

```
session_start();

$query_user = "SELECT username, profilepic FROM user where     username=".$_SESSION['valid_user'];//or 
$user = mysql_query($query_user, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($user);
$totalRows_user = mysql_num_rows($user);
```

Comment: thanks, but I still have a problem. I edited the question and added the login code for you to look at. I changed all $_SESSION['username'] to $_SESSION['valid_user'] and made the changes in content.php (adding the SELECT username, profilepic FROM user where username=".$_SESSION['valid_user']), but I get : Unknown column 'user' in 'where clause'. what can be causing the problem?

Comment: have you put the session_start(); in the starting of the page

Comment: yes, in both of the files (index.php - from where you log in and content.php - where you are redirected)

Comment: in which page you are getting the error? and one more thing is here you have to put single quotes like this `where username='".$_SESSION['valid_user']."'";`

Comment: on the `content.php` - as I'm redirected there after succesful login

Comment: it worked with the correct quotation marks that is `username='".$_SESSION['valid_user']."'";;` as well as with `username=\"".$_SESSION['valid_user']."\";";`. thanks for the help!

Comment: however, if no one is logged in and `content.php` is open (let's say a user has logged in and opened `content.php` in two tabs, logged in one and then refreshed another) there is displayed a notice: Notice: Undefined index: valid_user - how do I fix this/redirect back to `index.php` in this case?

Comment: when a user logged out then you have to set the session empty like this `$_SESSION['valid_user']="";` and in `content.php` also you have to check the session like if(isset($_SESSION['valid_user'])){ your code} else {not logged in}

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is a stateless protocol.

That means (for our discussion) that the server doesn't know that you are the same guy who logged in in the previous transaction he handled. Therefore you need to identify yourself each time.
This is accomplished with sessions. Session identifier is a unique string that identifies a specific client. In every request the client makes the session identifier is included either as a GET, POST or COOKIE variable.

It is unproductive and dangerous to send each and every time the user name and password to the server. What you should do instead is:

Check the username and password that the user sends to your php script. If the credentials are correct execute

```
session_start();
```

Then you should store the session identifier (which is a random string)  returned from

```
session_id();
```

in a database table that has two columns. The first column is for your random string and the second for storing the primary key value of the row from your users table that holds the data of the user that sent you his credentials. An script that would do that is:

```
$userResult = mysql_query('select id from users where binary userName = \''. 
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userName']) .'\' and binary passWord= \''.
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passWord']) .'\'');
if (mysql_num_rows($userResult))
{
     start_session();
     $userId = mysql_fetch_row($userResult);
     mysql_query('insert into sessions (sessionId, userId) values (\''.
     mysql_real_escape_string(session_id()) .'\', \''. (int)$userId[0] .'\')');
}else
{
     //handle user supplying bad username or password 
}
```

Each time the user sends a request you should find out who he is:

```
session_start();
$inputSessionIdentifier = mysql_real_escape_string(session_id());
$result = mysql_query('select * from sessions where sessionId = \''.
$inputSessionIdentifier .'\'');
if (mysql_num_rows($result))
{
     // user is already logged in, lets find out his data
     $sessionData = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
     $userResult = mysql_query('select * from users where id=\''. 
     mysql_real_escape_string($sessionData['userId']) .'\'');
     $userData = mysql_fetch_assoc($userResult);
     echo 'Hello '. $userData['userName']; 
}else
{
     //user is not logged in, ask for credentials or whatever ...
}
```

an example definition of the sessions table could be :

```
create table sessions ( sessionId varchar(255) not null, 
                        userId int(10) unsigned not null, 
                        unique(sessionId));
```

assuming that your users table has an unsigned integer primary key and is defined along the lines of :

```
create table users (id int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, 
                    userName varchar(16) not null,
                    passWord varchar(100) not null,
                    unique(userName));
```

Have in mind that sessions must expire and the relevant table should be purged of inactive sessions. That means that a real life script would be a tad more complex...

**IMPORTANT SECURITY ISSUE!**

The sample above assumes that you are storing plain text passwords in your database. This is **WRONG** and ***a very poor security practice***. Passwords should always be stored in an encrypted (hashed) form preferably the one generated by the blowfish cypher.

Comment: Please note that the accepted answer has huge security issues. It is very easy to bypass the login system altogether as long as you know a username. Unfortunately i am a new user and cannot comment and downvote it due to low reputation ...

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! :) upvoted your answer too ;) could you take a look at my comment under feroz akbars answer - i have an issue with the code, maybe you could help. :)

Comment: I strongly suggest not to use that solution. It is very easy for any unauthorized user to send you a cookie named valid_user with the appropriate "sauce" so as to look like a legitimate session variable.

As far as the notice is concerned you must never assume a variable/cookie or whatever is set. It is good practice to check if it is set first. Something like :

    if (!isset($_SESSION['valid_user']))
    {
         // not a valid user, redirect to index.php
    }